# How to programately record HDMI video?

Tags: video, hdmi

I am looking for a device that can be used, via an API, to record HDMI video.

I found several devices on the web but I am looking for one that does have an API that I could call and schedule recordings, that could be analysed lately.

Please specify if you were successful doing thing.

Comment: ffmpeg can record from capture devices these days, FWIW...(assuming you mean windows, it uses dshow api)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capture in software, you need HDMI capture card with SDK and/or a driver to one of the well-known capture APIs, such as DirectShow in MS Windows. Something like this: [Blackmagic Design Intensity](http://www.blackmagic-design.com/products/intensity/) or [XtremeRGB-Ex4+ (PCIe)](http://www.xtremergb.com/products/XtremeRGB%252dEx4%252b-%28PCIe%29.html).

Comment: Thanks, I emailed them for confirmation regarding SDK availability.